# Magento 2.X: Display save price of configurable product

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, price

I am working in Magento 2 I have display save the price of the simple product in category page, the home page, product page but I can not display save the price of configurable product

example: regular price: 50, special price = 25  so now I want to display in "you save 25 and saved 50%"

screenshot link: https://www.screencast.com/t/8StnVLywdW

Thanks in advance